# Sometime, Log4j write to old file, doesn't write to current file?

Tags: logging, log4j

I have a application which is logging using log4j (log4j-1.2.17.jar). I use DailyRollingFileAppender to rotate my logs daily.

Here's my log4j config:

```html
og4j.rootLogger=INFO, MM_SOCK, R, A1

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}: %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd 
log4j.appender.R.File=../log/charging.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}: %m%n

log4j.logger.10.55.53.157-Charging01=INFO, logAgent, FILE
log4j.appender.logAgent=com.mm.logagent.LogAgentAppender
log4j.appender.logAgent.mmIp=10.55.53.157

log4j.appender.logAgent.bufferSize=5000
log4j.appender.logAgent.retryConnect=1
log4j.appender.logAgent.retryInterval=15000
log4j.appender.logAgent.sleep=10000
log4j.appender.logAgent.Threshold=INFO

log4j.appender.MM_SOCK=com.mmserver.log.appender.AdvanceSocketHubAppender
log4j.appender.MM_SOCK.port=8004
log4j.appender.MM_SOCK.maxConnection=3
log4j.appender.MM_SOCK.maxQueue=5000
log4j.appender.MM_SOCK.offlineMaxQueue=100
```

This issue is sometime Log4j append new log into the old file, not the current file.

For example, today is 30/10/2015, current file is app.log, but sometimes log is appended to old file, such as app.log.2015-10-25.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
log4j.appender.R.Append=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! i'll try it, but what was the problem?